# Has anyone implemented a javascript UI framework, using an OO/prototype based style for writing code?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, prototype-programming

I'm specifically looking for a framework written using a coding style that is using a [prototype based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) OO style (that is, an OO style that relies on cloning rather than subclassing when instantiating objects). Has/is anyone writing such a framework?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dhtml library reference](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Internet/DHTML/Scripts_and_Examples/) to find the source code for projects like [dynapi](http://dynapi.sourceforge.net/releases/dynapi-3.0.0-beta2/src/dynapi.js) or [activewidgets](http://www.activewidgets.com/runtime/2.5/lib/aw.js), which were written prior to the current trends.